# Access simple SQL join

Tags: sql, ms-access

very simple SQL join in Access. fields are both text.

```
SELECT * from
houses join munzip
on
houses.MUN_CODE = munzip.GOOD MUN;
```

giving me this error

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'houses.MUN_CODE = munzip.GOOD MUN'

there all some nulls in the houses.MUN_CODE field

I am new to SQL so please don't bash me.

Comment: That space in your column name `GOOD MUN` looks odd.  Try escaping it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
SELECT * 
from houses 
inner join munzip
    on houses.MUN_CODE = munzip.[GOOD MUN];
```

SQL queries don't accept names with a space, so in Access you should surround it with square brackets.

Comment: tried your way but now it is telling me there is a syntax error in the from clause. the tables are named correctly

Comment: got it, access dont have `implicit inner join`

Comment: You probably need to specify the type of join (`INNER`, `LEFT,` `RIGHT`)